# How to fix num validation and 0 value error code to work as well as concatenating multiple errors to show at once

Tags: php, error-handling

Basically the user must input a tempt start and end value along with what they want the charts increments to be by. and this is the code for the errors that the program is supposed to pick up. My code is not working for the

error where the user enters a text value instead of a number
and the error when the user inputs a zero does not work but if the user inputs a negative number... it works (so thats really confusing)

also I dont know why I cannot concatenate all of my errors to allow multiple errors to show at once

Can you please check the other areas aside the problematic areas just to make sure?

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    try 
    {
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"){
        $start = "";
        $stop = "";
        $incr = "";
    }
    else if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $start=(double)trim($_POST["starting_number"]);
        $stop=(double)trim($_POST["stop_number"]);
        $incr=(double)trim($_POST["increment_number"]);
        $num = (double)($stop-$start)/$incr;
        if($start == "" | $stop == "" | $incr == "" | $num == ""){
        //means the user did not enter anything
        $error .= "You must enter something into the text box.";
        echo $error;
        }
        //the conditions will cause too many iterations
        else if($num>$MAX_ITERATIONS)
        {
            $error .= "The conditions will cause too many iterations (max. 100), therefore (for the sake of server resources) your request is denied.";
            echo $error;
        }
        //When the user inputs the starting temperature larger than the ending temperature
        else if($start > $stop)
        {
            $error .= "The starting temperature cannot be larger than the ending temperature, please try again";
            echo $error;
        }
```

this is mainly where I am having issues

```
        //When the increment value is <=0
        else if($incr = "0")
        {
            $error .= "You must enter a positve, non-zero increment.";
            echo $error;
        }
        //means the user entered something, but not a number
        else if(!is_numeric($num))
        {
        $error .= "The value entered <u>MUST</u> be a number, you entered" .$num;
        echo $error;
        }
```

I think everything else below is fine but please check just incase

```
        else
        {  
            echo "<table border='1'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Celcius</th>";
            echo "<th>Fahrenheit</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            for($i=$start; $i<=$stop; $i += $incr)
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>". $i . "°</td>";
                echo "<td>". (($i * 9/5) + 32 ). "°</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
                echo "</table>";
                }
                if($error == "")
                {
                    $output = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    $error .= "<br/>Please try again.";
                }
        }
    }
    catch(DivisionByZeroError $e)
    {
        echo "The text boxes cannot be blank.";
    }
        catch(Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'Please Enter correctly';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did some typecasting, but did not compare against them correctly.

1. When casting by `(double)` the result of casting an empty string is `0`
   Thus, this should never be true:

`if($start == "" | $stop == "" | $incr == "" | $num == ""){`

You basically should change this to

```
if($start === 0 | $stop === 0 | $incr === 0 | $num === 0){
```

for correct comparison against a zero, because thats the casting result of an empty string.

However, a given 0 (via POST) could be a correct value logicalwise, so you may set a different default value of say -1 instead

```
$start=(double)trim($_POST["starting_number"] ?? "-1");
$stop=(double)trim($_POST["stop_number"] ?? "-1");
$incr=(double)trim($_POST["increment_number"] ?? "-1");
if($start < 0 | $stop < 0 | $incr < 0 | $num < 0){
```

2. 

You created an assignment to $incr istead of a condition, thus it won't work, because the assignment is always `true`
Also keep in mind the previous typecasting so check the type aswell via triple =

Instead of

```
else if($incr = "0")
```

do

```
else if($incr === 0)
```

3. Because of the typecasing to `double` this will also never be true because `$num` will always be numeric

`else if(!is_numeric($num))`

Following the above mentioned changes this should be changed to

```
else if($num < 0)
```

instead